# How to define a BOOL constant?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know how to do it for a float:

```
#define kMyConstant 1.0f
```

but how could I do that fora BOOL value?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`#define kMyConstantBOOL YES`

Or

`static BOOL MyConstantBool = YES;`

Comment: I like the latter as you get some type checking and can view it and use it as a symbol in the debugger.

Comment: did you mean "const" rather than "static"?  static BOOL is a variable.

Comment: @progrmr would static const be appropriate? Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is static means there's only one instance of the variable, and const means it can't change. So static const will make sure it's always the same value and doesn't take up extra memory with new instances?

Comment: `static` specifies the scope and lifetime of the variable ([more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1795448/1693173)), whereas `const` specifies that it can't be changed.  `BOOL const MyConstantBool = YES;` would be preferred.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example:

```
#define kMyConstant      YES
#define kMyOtherConstant NO
```

Answer (score 7):

I would do it differently:

```
enum { MyConstantBool = YES };
```

It's a constant, it doesn't take up storage space.