# Difference between declaring static variable inside and outside the implementation context in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I have to declare static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662903/where-do-i-have-to-declare-static-variables)

I've seen code like

```
@implementation ClassA

static NSString *str = nil;

.....

@end
```

as well as

```
static NSString *str = nil;

@implementation ClassA

.....

@end
```

What's the difference if a static var is declared inside the @implmentation context vs outside

Comment: Pls refer this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662903/where-do-i-have-to-declare-static-variables

Comment: @7KV7 if you aren't adding any content *of your own*, a comment is preferred

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There is no difference between**

```
@implementation ClassA

static NSString *str = nil;

.....

@end
```

and

```
static NSString *str = nil;

@implementation ClassA

.....

@end
```

They work the same way ...

> Static variables help give the class
>   object more functionality than just 
>   that of a "factory" producing
>   instances; it can approach being a 
>   complete and versatile object in its
>   own right. A class object can be  used
>   to coordinate the instances it
>   creates, dispense instances from 
>   lists of objects already created, or
>   manage other processes essential to 
>   the application. In the case when you
>   need only one object of a  particular
>   class, you can put all the object's
>   state into static  variables and use
>   only class methods. This saves the
>   step of allocating  and initializing
>   an instance.